# Why does the Swift interpreter provide memory locations for instances that throw runtime errors, but not class names?

Tags: swift

I am trying to debug my Swift application. Below is the error message that I am receiving.

[image]

In the image, it is clear that the interpreter knows where the instance of the class is. So why doesn't the error message provide a class name to go with the error in this case? Thank you!

Comment: There is no Swift interpreter. The only implementations of Swift (that I know of) are the open source Apple implementation (which is compiled, via LLVM), and RemObjects Silver (which is cross-compiled to the CLR, JVM, WebAssembly or several other targets).

Comment: But how are runtime errors thrown without an interpreter?

Comment: What makes you think an interpreter is necessary for throwing a runtime error? An error is just the program printing an error message, and exiting (by calling the `exit` system call) with a non-zero (= "bad") exit code. The machine code that does that could have been compile ahead of time by a compiler like Swift's, it could be just-in-time compiled with most Java implementations, or it could baked into an interpreter like CPython's. It doesn't really matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does. The full error has the form:

```
objc[9596]: -[main.Foo a_missing_method]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa711505390 (no message forward handler is installed)
```

`-[main.Foo a_missing_method]` is telling you that the selector `a_missing_method` was being sent to an instance of class `main.Foo` (a method being sent to the class itself would use a `+` instead of a `-`).